# Where is the money hidden?

Tags: wordplay

Recently, Alice robbed a bank and had her accomplice, Bill, hide the money in a house on one of many streets in the city. (The police have already arrested both Alice and Bill.) The police are confident that if they find the street the house is on, they can find the house containing the money. They've asked you to find out what street the house is on.

Oh, and also one more thing, here's a note that Alice left for Bill. It was found at the scene of the crime (it doesn't seem awfully helpful but you can have it nonetheless):

> 1:10 AVERY

To help you in your search, the police have provided you with a list of 15 possible streets they believe the house with the money could be located on (in no particular order):

1. Oak Boulevard
2. Main Street
3. 8th Cross
4. King's Road
5. Mueller Lane
6. 72nd Avenue
7. 64th Crossing
8. Palace Street
9. 2nd Main Street
10. 110th Lane
11. Maple Avenue
12. Argon Street
13. Rocky Boulevard
14. 13th Street
15. 99th Avenue

**What street contains the house that the money is hidden on?**

Comment: AVERY street, number 10, first flat. Why not?:)

Comment: @nikamed sounds like an answer to me, it's not what I had in mind though :)

Comment: I still can not understand how the police know that the thief had an accomplice, the accomplice has the money and the note is for the accomplice while they are both are unidentified to the police. Is there something missing?

Comment: @nikamed edited to make the question clearer.

Comment: Surely the police could also provide a list of streets in the city?

Comment: @f'' the police have assumed that you're adept enough to figure out the street without a list.

Comment: Should I add a hint? Both answers so far are incorrect.

Comment: Also, why the close votes?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but those who did marked it "too broad", presumably on the grounds that they doubt you've actually given enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Seeing as how the question is now closed, any ideas on how to reopen it? I can't think of anything except giving revealing hints that give away the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't any clever ideas. If any of the people who voted to close are reading this, they might want to comment...

Comment: As one of the people who VTC'd this question, I will offer my reasoning for it. The actual puzzle in this question comes down to the words `1:10 AVERY`, because no matter how I look at it, the story preceding it appears to be purely creative fluff, without a cue to think in a particular direction. If the story is meant to make a pop culture reference, then it does very weakly in that regard too because I can't associate it with anything specific. Just having the words `1:10 AVERY` as the puzzle invites answers from all over the place, which is what we tried to avoid by VTC'ing this question.

Comment: @CodeNewbie The puzzle does not try to make a pop culture reference. The puzzle's words, as you say, are merely creative fluff. The actual puzzle boils down to how you can make 1:10 AVERY can correspond to a street name. Have you any ideas on how I can make the puzzle less broad?

Comment: Try adding hints (preferably weaved into the story rather than explicit ones) which give some indication as to the answer. Based on the two answers already received, I reckon you'd agree that it is indeed quite broad at the moment.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I've edited to make the question less broad, please reconsider your close vote now.

Comment: I didn't particularly like this style of making it less broad, but it'll do. In the future, try to craftily weave hints into your story which can make it less broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK this is wrong because it's imperfect, but what the hell.

> 72nd Avenue

because

> 1:10 is 70 seconds. Then there's AVE which is short for avenue.

It's imperfect because

> The RY part doesn't belong.

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: What about the imperfection?

Comment: The AVE is disguised within the name Avery. The first three letters are the only significant part.

Answer (score 4):

> 1, 10th Avenue (nr. Railway St.?)

Comment: Incorrect. Note that you only have to provide me with the street name, not the house number.

Answer (score 3):

> KEOBI street

Because

> if you add 10 (1:10) to each letter it gives you that "name".

Comment: Good idea but incorrect.

Comment: @fi12 oops, put the wrong first and last letters. Probably still wrong though.

Comment: Still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably incorrect but:

> Rocky Boulevard

Because:

> It contains all the letters in AVERY
>  A bit abstract but: it also has 15 letters
>  the "1" in 1:10 represents the number of letters in AVERY
>  and the 10 represents 10, so 5 + 10 = 15